# Cocos2d-x compile android cannot run program

Tags: cocos2d-x, cocos2d-android

created new cocos2d-x 3.6 project with cocos console comnand new -l cpp, all variables are set by running setup.py, then when i try to run cocos compile i get compilation errors.

log: [log.txt](http://pastebin.com/60fXYjpn)

Cheked if there are spaces in paths but there isn't, everything is installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is here

> Execute failed: java.io.IOEx ception:
>
> Cannot run program"D:\MyCppGame\cocos2d\cocos\platform\android\java\${
>   aapt}"
>
> (in directory "D:\MyCppGame\cocos2d\cocos\platform\android\java"):
>
> Create Process error=2, The system cannot find the file specified

You can solve it by adding some lines to the SDK/tools/ant/build.xml

[https://stackoverflow.com/a/30807140](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30801483/ant-debug-and-ant-release-failed/30807140#30807140)